# How to mark super classes initializers as private in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, swift2, ios9

I would like to initialize a class with my designated initializer to avoid using the object without initializing all instance variables. For some reason, I couldn't mark init() method as private in Swift 2. I have marked init() as private in swift 1.2. Does it removed in Swift 2.0?. Is there anyway to mark init() as private!?

Comment: you can use internal, than it will be visible for your subclasses.

Comment: @dirtydanee: That is not quite correct. In Swift, internal access enables entities to be used within any source file from their defining module.

Comment: A concrete example would be helpful. The Swift compiler does not allow to  create objects without initializing all instance variables.

Comment: Swift's "Lazy Stored Properties" offers an elegant solution to initializing instance variables. They get initialized just once, but only when accessed for the first time. This also can eliminate the need to make them optionals. It's a great feature!

Comment: My question is if I have a class which has to be initialised with array of strings, it should be initialised with only that initialiser. I don't want the instance of the class created with any other initialiser.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should try this pattern:

```
class PrivateInitObject: NSObject {

var text: String!    

 internal init(withText text: String){    
    super.init()

    self.text = text

  }
}
```

and after that you can see there is no public init()

```
class someClass {

   let obj = PrivateInitObject(withText: "some text")
   let obj2 = PrivateInitObject() // compile error, init() is private
}
```

Comment: We can  use `@available` attribute to make it unavaliable for the users. But I don't think it is thebest way to do it.